# I'm a grantee and my boss told me he would like me to stay but I don't know what to do

Tags: career-development, job-change

**Intro:**
I'm studying in the afternoons and I work as a grantee on the mornings. I have been a grantee for 6 months now, and I still have 2 months to go. Once finished I have the choice myself to leave or join the company. I pretty much like the work we do, the projects we have ongoing and the future projects we are going to develop in a field I don't have much experience and I will learn lots.

So, the other day my boss told me he would like me to stay in the company once my grantee contract ends and he would hire me part time until finishing my lectures, when he would hire me full-time. I'm pretty happy about it because that will be my first full time job as something I have learned and I like... But I don't know if I want to stop studying next year or I want to go and follow my own projects and ideas I have which differ from the developing field.

I am afraid if I don't give him a positive answer about staying in the company he won't even hire me once I finish the grantee in 2 months time, even though I would still have myself 4 months after the grantee period finishes of lectures before ending the course and thinking what I want to do next.

The easy answer would be tell him that I would stay and then once the time comes, if I feel like I don't want to be there anymore or I want to go and study next Semptember tell him with-in a month time and leave before the classes start.. But that would be very selfish and I would not feel great after doing that..

But he asked me for an answer as soon as possible and I don't have any single clue of how could I manage this situation professionally and as friendly as possible.

Comment: what is a grantee?

Comment: @Kilisi For the context I will guess is some kind of internship.  From google `a person to whom a grant or conveyance is made.`

Answer (score 4):

Being hired, even full time, does not mean that you have to stop studying or developing your own projects and ideas.  Many people work full time and go to school/work on projects.  If you would like to work for the company then let your boss know.  You don't need to tell him anything about how you may feel in the future because even you don't know.  When the time comes that your feelings about the position and the direction you want to go change, you can make a decision then.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with extending a student job, even if you do intend to look elsewhere once you're done with school.  You can't guarantee that you'll be able to find a better job by the time you graduate or shortly afterwards.

It's almost always safer and easier to find a new job while employed, so you generally shouldn't quit your current job until you've got a replacement.